# python list comprehension alphabet generation

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am trying to make use of list comprehension.

My intended aim of the code is 
come with the values,

```
['aaaa','bb','cccc','ddddddd','eee','f','ggggg']
```

and it should not display values beyond `'g'` based on number of elements in the list.

If I have 8 elements in another list `b` then it should display `'h'` too.

Can I achieve this via list comprehension with two for loops?

```
import string
b = [4, 2, 4, 7, 3, 1, 5]
d = [ s*i for i in range(len(b)) for s in list(string.ascii_lowercase) ]
```

I tried to use this code but in vain

```
[chr(i) for i in range(ord('a'), ord('z') + 1)]
```

Comment: Don't use a nested loop, use `zip()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just the [`zip()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) together your list `b` and the `string.ascii_lowercase` string:

```
[char * count for char, count in zip(string.ascii_lowercase, b)]
```

`zip()` pairs up the elements of the input sequences; first character of `string.ascii_lowercase` with the first number in `b`, second character with the second number in `b`, etc. until one or the other has run out of elements.

Demo:

```
>>> import string
>>> b = [4, 2, 4, 7, 3, 1, 5]
>>> [char * count for char, count in zip(string.ascii_lowercase, b)]
['aaaa', 'bb', 'cccc', 'ddddddd', 'eee', 'f', 'ggggg']
>>> [char * count for char, count in zip(string.ascii_lowercase, b + [3])]
['aaaa', 'bb', 'cccc', 'ddddddd', 'eee', 'f', 'ggggg', 'hhh']
>>> [char * count for char, count in zip(string.ascii_lowercase, b + [3, 7])]
['aaaa', 'bb', 'cccc', 'ddddddd', 'eee', 'f', 'ggggg', 'hhh', 'iiiiiii']
```

Comment: this is the pythonic way to do it, without unnecessary indexing (i.e. with a low complexity)

Answer (score 3):

```
import string
s=list(string.ascii_lowercase)
b = [4, 2, 4, 7, 3, 1, 5]
[s[i]*x for i,x in enumerate(b)]
>>>['aaaa', 'bb', 'cccc', 'ddddddd', 'eee', 'f', 'ggggg']
```

Comment: Thanks for another solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
b = [4, 2, 4, 7, 3, 1, 5]

print b

out = [b[i]*chr(ord('a')+i) for i in range(len(b))]
print out
```

This gives:

```
[4, 2, 4, 7, 3, 1, 5]
['aaaa', 'bb', 'cccc', 'ddddddd', 'eee', 'f', 'ggggg']
```

Comment: This is what is I was trying to get. Thanks.